# How can I discover which side of a rectangle a collision occurred on?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, geometry, collision-detection

I have been struggling for a while with something that seems basic. I can't think of an effective mathematical way to look at this problem. The language I am using is Objective-C, but I can convert pretty much any language answer because it is essentially just math.

I have two squares, one being the player, on being an obstacle. The player can move, the obstacle can't. **The end goal** is to tell which side it came from upon collision. For example, when I am moving down it detects that I hit the top of the obstacle.

**Here is what I know:**

1. The location of the player both before and after the collision
2. Whether or not there is any intersection taking place
3. Almost all other aspects of the movement (velocity, directional movement, etc.)

I will provide as much information as I can, but all I need is a general method for doing this. There seems to be so many ways to approach this, but every one has flaws :/

I am not really asking for code, although that would be nice, I just need a concept to get to working.

Comment: Direction from whose point of view? At what kind of resolution (left/right/up/down, compass points, angle)? How are you determining that there's a collision in the first place? Can you briefly go over the flawed solutions you've found, so no-one wastes time repeating them?

Comment: I went to sleep after posting this so I havent got to responding until now. Sorry! :/

I know the direction in relation to where its coming from.

I can tell when any collision occurs by testing whether there is overlap between both the obstacle, and the destination of the player. So, if the player tries to pass through the obstacle, I would know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate on which side of the center of the obstacle rectangle is the center of the player rectangle just before the collision. The center is mean of max and min points in rectangle.
This can be done using difference of x and y co-ordinates of both center.
Remember to take the cordinate which is less than sum of l1/2 + l2/2 .
conclusions:-

```
    (x1,y1) = center of obstacle
    (x2,y2) = center of player
     dx = y1-y2
     dy = x1-x2

    l1 & l2 are length of side aligned in that direction

    dx<0 && abs(dx)>(l1/2+l2/2) = left of obstacle

    dx>0 && abs(dx)>(l1/2+l2/2) = right of obstacle

    dy<0 && abs(dy)>(l1/2+l2/2) = below

    dy>0 && abs(dy)>(l1/2+l2/2) = above
```

Comment: I didn't go word for word, but this concept got it to work :D

I had to tinker with it for a while, particularly to work with more than one obstacle, but this was fundamentally what I needed to work with. Cheers.

Comment: @IAmTheAg It was very difficult explain on paper and i didnt think that u would get what i wanted tell but i am glad u got it.